# Can a pattern synonym have a different type signature in each direction, like numeric literals do?

Tags: haskell, pattern-synonyms

Consider the numeric literal `1`. It has a different type depending on whether it's used on the left or right of the equals sign. In `f True = 1`, `1` has type `Num p => p`. But in `f 1 = True`, `1` has type `(Eq a, Num a) => a`. Is it possible to create a pattern synonym that works the same way? For example:

```
pattern LooksLikeFoo :: (Read a, Show a) => a
pattern LooksLikeFoo <- (show -> "Foo")
  where LooksLikeFoo = read "Foo"
```

That pattern only works if it has both the `Read` and `Show` classes, no matter which side of the equals sign it's on. Is there a way to make it have type `Show a => a` on the left side of the equals sign, but `Read a => a` on the right side? Non-working pseudo-code:

```
pattern LooksLikeFoo :: Show a => a
pattern LooksLikeFoo <- (show -> "Foo")
  where LooksLikeFoo :: Read a => a
        LooksLikeFoo = read "Foo"
```

Comment: No this isn't possible, I know Edward Kmett has wanted this

Comment: @Iceland_jack If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it. Also, can you include a link in it to where Edward Kmett talked about wanting it?

Comment: I don't think it would be too theory-heavy to implement, but giving good ergonomics would be tricky. Patsyn types are already quite complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible currently but it has been brought up by Edward Kmett as a possibility a few times, for example: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/eqhcgx/comment/fetsa54